# Open multiple urls in browser with selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to open multiple url on the browser with the following command

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Java\\Library\\seleniumhq\\chromedriver_win32_2.40.exe");
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

    openNewTab(webDriver, "http://dantri.com.vn/phap-luat.htm", 1);
    openNewTab(webDriver, "http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.htm", 2);
    openNewTab(webDriver, "http://dantri.com.vn/the-gioi.htm", 3);
    openNewTab(webDriver, "http://dantri.com.vn/the-thao.htm", 4);
    openNewTab(webDriver, "http://dantri.com.vn/giao-duc-khuyen-hoc.htm", 5);

}

public void openNewTab(WebDriver webDriver, String url, int position) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.open()");

    ArrayList<String>  tabs = new ArrayList<>(webDriver.getWindowHandles());
    System.out.println("tabs : " + tabs.size() + " >position: " + position + " >\t" + url);
    webDriver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(position));

    webDriver.get(url);
}
```

Although the browser tab has been opened, tabs.size () remains the same, resulting in an error.

```
tabs : 2 >position: 1 > http://dantri.com.vn/phap-luat.htm
tabs : 2 >position: 2 > http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.htm
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at test.test.NewClass.openNewTab(NewClass.java:37)
    at test.test.NewClass.<init>(NewClass.java:25)
    at test.test.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:43)
```

Please help me fix it

Comment: Please add 'String' parameter to ArrayList. Here tabs = new ArrayList<String>(webDriver.getWindowHandles());

Comment: Tested by you, but it's still buggy

Comment: Please also check by removing Static keyword from this line "static ArrayList<String> tabs"

Comment: still does not work

Comment: Are you getting same exeception ? Check with debugger, Where exactly you are getting null values/responce.

Comment: I usually find fault with sout on netbean. Sorry but I do not know how to use debug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173525/discussion-between-kien-dnh-and-ishita-shah).

Answer (score 2):

Change your openNewTab method as static method . I am not getting the exception and getting the response as expected.

**Modified Code:**

```
public class MultiTab {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver webDriver =new ChromeDriver();
        openNewTab(webDriver, "http://dantri.com.vn/phap-luat.htm", 1);
        openNewTab(webDriver, "http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.htm", 2);
        openNewTab(webDriver, "http://dantri.com.vn/the-gioi.htm", 3);
        openNewTab(webDriver, "http://dantri.com.vn/the-thao.htm", 4);
        openNewTab(webDriver, "http://dantri.com.vn/giao-duc-khuyen-hoc.htm", 5);
    }

    public static void openNewTab(WebDriver webDriver, String url, int position) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.open()");
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(webDriver.getWindowHandles());
        System.out.println("tabs : " + tabs.size() + " >position: " + position + " >\t" + url);
        webDriver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(position));
        webDriver.get(url);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
tabs : 2 >position: 1 > http://dantri.com.vn/phap-luat.htm
tabs : 3 >position: 2 > http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.htm
tabs : 4 >position: 3 > http://dantri.com.vn/the-gioi.htm
tabs : 5 >position: 4 > http://dantri.com.vn/the-thao.htm
tabs : 6 >position: 5 > http://dantri.com.vn/giao-duc-khuyen-hoc.htm
```

Comment: I still faulty, can you please give me the selemium version and chromedriver you use it

Comment: I am using Selenium Version: 3.11.0

Comment: I checked the command it does not work properly, may be wrong when the tabs = new ArrayList<>(webDriver.getWindowHandles());  are not updated value.I want the statement to be more stable than to continue helping me

Comment: if pass two urls its opening 3 tabs... i want to open only 2 tabs for 2 urls